# Convergence of series/absolute convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $y_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that for all sequences of real numbers $x_n$ with $\lim x_n =0$  the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n y_n $ converges. Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |y_n| $ converges.

---

I deleted my solution... All i know/extract from the exercise is that $\lim x_n y_n =0$ and $\lim x_n =0$. Now I'm stuck. I don't know how to continue. Any hints appreciated. I know many criterions/ tests that should help me examine if the series converges, yet I cannot apply them.. because I do  not know if $\lim |y_n| =0$. If it does not the series clearly diverges.

Comment: It's not true that if $x_ny_n$ and $x_n$ tend to $0$, then $y_n$ tends to 0

Comment: Yes.. you can find counterexamples.. ! You're right.. I guess I have to reconsider there

Comment: Now, that I take a better look at the exercise.. I don't where to start... !! Since the other observation I made was useless.. Any hints?

Comment: You note that your proposed solution is wrong. You should probably edit your question to remove that "solution" and add any other work you have done so far on the problem.

Comment: It is interesting to note that this means that $\sum{1\over\log n}y_n$ converges, along with many other sequences where $x$ approaches $0$ even more slowly.  Perhaps this is an approach you could take: construct a sequence of sequences of $x_n$ each of which converge to $0$ but increasingly slowly...

Comment: I'm not that good at doing this.. that is construting sequences that the series converges slowly.. But I am aware of some sequences that do converge slowly...

Comment: Well, for example, $x_{n,k}={1\over n^{1/k}}$ for increasing $k$...

Comment: By the way, I thought the Dirichlet test... that since $\sum x_n y_n $ converges if $y_n $ is of a limit zero and decreasing and $\sum x_n $ has bounded partial sums

Comment: @abiessu How would did this help?Ok, $x_{n, k} $ does  satifsy the limit, plus $\lim x_n y_n =0$. How how I can relate it with $y_n$ and the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to see $\lim |y_n| =0$: if the sequence of non-negative terms $|y_n|$ does not converge to $0$, then there is $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence of indices $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots$, such that $|y_{n_k}| > \epsilon$ for $k = 1, 2, \ldots$. Define a sequence $x_n$ such that

$$x_{n_k} = \frac{\mathrm{sgn}(y_{n_k})}{k} $$

and $x_n$ is $0$ if $n$ is not one of the $n_k$. Then $\lim x_n = 0$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ny_n$ is not convergent, as the subsequence comprising its non-zero elements is bounded below by the harmonic sequence $\frac{\epsilon}{k}$. This contradicts our assumptions, so we must have $\lim|y_n| = 0$.

To answer the main question, assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n|$ does not converge, then there is a sequence of indices $N_1< N_2 < \ldots$ such that the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N_k}|y_n| > k$, $k = 1, 2 \ldots$. Now define
$$
x_n = \frac{\mathrm{sgn}(y_{n})}{\sqrt{k_n}}
$$
where $k_n$ is the least $k$ such that $n \le N_k$. then $\lim x_n = 0$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{N_k}x_ny_n > \frac{k}{\sqrt{k}} = \sqrt{k}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ny_n$ is not convergent, contradicting our assumptions.

Comment: Ok.. but this answers partially the problem... How to prove that thse series converges? It is not necessary that if the sequence goes to zero, then the series converges. Example is $1/n$.

Comment: You said you needed to know that $\lim{y_n} = 0$, I answered that part of your question, because I thought you meant you could take it from there.

Comment: Well, If I knew that the sequence was zero (which you showed very nicely) then I would be able to apply some tests. But , playing around with the tests well I did not get anything useful. Or for example use the following sentence:

$$\lim \left| \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n} \right| =\ell \implies \lim \sqrt[n]{y_n} =\ell.$$

Comment: Hint: the approach of the above proof works for your main question: assume $\sum|y_n|$ diverges and use that to design a sequence $x_n$ such that $\sum x_ny_n$ diverges.

Comment: I'll try that... thank you for the moment.

Comment: As you gave me a tick, I thought I better actually answer the question, but don't look until you've had a go yourself :-)